# How to update selected record set in the same function?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How can I select some rows, updating those at the same time?
Now I have a function that simply does select:

```
RETURN (SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
                                ...
                             )) from (
    select ...));
```

And now I want to update rows that was selected in the inner `select`;

Comment: So you want the function to return the results prior to the updates?

Comment: @Hambone doesn't matter. Client doesn't need this field